# Reading XML with

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to extract the author from this:

```
<icon>
    <tags>
        <tag>steam</tag>
    </tags>
    <author>Author Name</author>
    <authorwebsite>http://www.domain.com/</authorwebsite>
    <license>
        Creative Commons (Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 3.0 Unported)
    </license>
    <licensewebsite>http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/</licensewebsite>
    <iconset>Name</iconset>
    <iconsetid>slug</iconsetid>
    <attribution/>
    <additionalsizes>
        <icon>
            <id>99633</id>
            <size>128</size>
            <tags/>
            <image>
                http://url1
            </image>
        </icon>
        <icon>
            <id>99633</id>
            <size>256</size>
            <tags/>
            <image>
                http://url2
            </image>
        </icon>
        <icon>
            <id>99633</id>
            <size>512</size>
            <tags/>
            <image>
                http://url3
            </image>
        </icon>
    </additionalsizes>
</icon>
```

I tried:

```
name = dom.getElementsByTagName('author')
print name[0].firstChild.nodeValue
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nodeValue'

And:

```
name = dom.getElementsByTagName('author')
print " ".join(t.nodeValue for t in name[0].childNodes if t.nodeType == t.TEXT_NODE)
```

Returns empty string.

What's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Are you tied to the DOM API? I'd switch to the ElementTree API instead; much easier. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: what XML package are you using?

Comment: @isedev I have from xml.dom.minidom import parse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), as suggested by @Martijn Pieters:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree.fromstring('<icon><author>Author Name</author></icon>')
print tree.find('author').text
```

Some more examples: http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/xml/etree/ElementTree/parse.html

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to get author from inside the icon tag

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
dom = parse('test.xml')
icon = dom.getElementsByTagName('icon')[0]
author = icon.getElementsByTagName('author')[0]
print author.firstChild.nodeValue
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasy with lxml:

```
from lxml import etree
dom=etree.fromstring(XML_DOC)
dom.xpath('/icon/author/text()')[0]
```

returns 'Author Name'